# Django : send mail from Gmail

Tags: django, email

I try to send mail from admin adress :

My view :

```
...
if request.method == "POST":
form = contactForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    sujet = form.cleaned_data['sujet']
    message= form.cleaned_data['message']
    try:
        mail_admins(subject=sujet, message=message)
...
```

My settings :

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "zor@gmail.com"
SERVER_EMAIL = "zor@gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "zor@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "mdp_of_zor@gmail.com"

ADMINS = [('Zorro', 'zor@gmail.com')]
```

But when I want to send mail from this view, I have this error :

```
SMTPAuthenticationError at /contact-admin

(534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsc\n5.7.14 aB9RwBxS9Q43rLo8piNoyzSjcewqxpgCnCkO6tyx-sse_8WkiANZHIGY3on1EP5iN9idsbA\n5.7.14 
xE5zrQPkaGzr_Xe585DeVpze3b3zOsKI6H18hXbwiBGvWclZ8CbmjRBu7RYFniGf2PbuIiq\n5.7.14 IMnCKmefwBzOk6OjtdwJ17m8zI76vD-xo8Z8Y7Baj3d1Xd54QekL593l-8fY5LG0xzWlP9\n5.7.14 54ZNmaiSaBEkpbV-l2RxUvDM5zyaJs> 
Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  
Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 198sm222847wml.22 - gsmtp')
```

Why have I this error ??

Comment: No, I already tested the process of this topic but it doesn't works

Comment: I receive a message in Gmail from Google : "... Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account zor@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards. ... "

Comment: The error message gives you instructions telling you what to do. You haven't given any more details of what you have done, so your question is a duplicate.